# MySQL: Is the read committed isolation level safe with mixed binary log format?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5

When using the MIXED format with the READ COMMITTED isolation level, am I safe?

The docs state (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_read-committed)

> If you use READ COMMITTED or enable innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog, you must use row-based binary logging

In the list of `When running in MIXED logging format, the server automatically switches from statement-based to row-based logging under the following conditions`

.. the isolation level is **not** mentioned: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-mixed.html

Furthermore, the following bug from 2006/2007 talks about adding an warning or error message if the isolation level is used with the incompatible log format. *See link to bug in the comment section*

I have tested the combination in MySQL 5.5 and I don't get any warning. So I assume that the row format is used if the isolation is used. Am I right?

**Update**

The following suggests that it is safe (that ROW will be used when having MIXED). Link to manual in the comments (I can't post more than 2 links)

> If you are using InnoDB tables and the transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED, only row-based logging can be used. It is ***possible*** to change the logging format to STATEMENT, but doing so at runtime leads very rapidly to errors because InnoDB can no longer perform inserts.

Comment: Link to bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23051

Comment: Why do you need "Read committed"?

Comment: I need it in order to prevent gap locking when using `select .. for update`. I select specific ids.

Comment: Link to manual, quote from the update: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-setting.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL Documentation : Mixed Binary Logging Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log-mixed.html)

> A given storage engine can support either or both logging formats. The following table lists the formats supported by each engine.

In the table mentioned under that sentence on that page

```
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|Storage Engine|Row Logging Supported|Statement Logging Supported       |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|ARCHIVE       |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|BLACKHOLE     |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|CSV           |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|EXAMPLE       |Yes                  |No                                |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|FEDERATED     |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|HEAP          |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|InnoDB        |Yes                  |Yes when the transaction          |
|              |                     |isolation level is REPEATABLE     | <== NOTE THIS
|              |                     |READ or SERIALIZABLE; No otherwise|
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|MyISAM        |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|MERGE         |Yes                  |Yes                               |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
|NDB           |Yes                  |No                                |
+--------------+---------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Thus, [binlog_format=MIXED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) is not supported for `READ COMMITTED`.